# Issue with chrome http://www.games-misc.com/?f

Tags: internet, virus, advertisements

I have a very annoying problem or possibly a computer virus. The Chrome browser keeps opening a new tab with the following URL:

> `http://www.games-misc.com/?f`

Automatically written in the address bar. This keeps happening unexpectedly and I think its timed to happen between 10-15 min intervals.

Does anyone know what the problem would be or how to solve it?

I tried the solution [posted here](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120210155925AABiKVI), but nothing changed.

Then I tried using [the Adwcleaner tool](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/adwcleaner/dl/125/) but still nothing.

Comment: First step delete Chrome's current user profile.

Comment: @Ramhound i did delete the current user now whats next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either caused by an extension that is installed on chrome or a malware/adware on your computer. We are going to first check and make sure this is a problem only with chrome. First of all, try and open another browser and confirm that this problem only occurs with Google Chrome. If that is the case, follow the step-by-step instructions below to remove the extension or delete the user profile. Otherwise skip to the next section, Adware/Malware Removal.

### Chrome Extension/Profile Removal

Extensions are the most likely cause for strange behavior and ads on chrome. Extensions can and mostly are installed through third-party desktop applications and sometimes even by other sneaky ways. To remove the once you don't recognize or want follow the instructions below:

1. Start Chrome and Open the Chrome Menu [image]
2. Go to Settings > Extensions (On the left hand side)
3. Delete all of the extensions that you haven't installed by pressing the trash button on the right. [image]

Test and see if the problem persists. If it does, you can try deleting your user profile. Follow this simple guide from the [Google support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en).

> 1. Open the window of the user you want to delete. Check the icon in
>      the top corner to make sure you're in the right user.
> 2. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu [image] on the browser toolbar.
> 3. Select **Settings**.
> 4. In the “Users” section, select the user that you want to delete.
> 5. Click **Delete**. Alternatively, you can click the **X** icon to the right of the user. Note: If there is only one user, you will see a
>      **Delete this user** button instead.
> 6. In the confirmation dialog that appears, click **Delete**.

Test and see if the problem still remains. If it does, follow the instructions in the next section.

---

### Adware/Malware Removal

A recent installation of a program could be causing the extension or the ads to appear. Start by checking to see if there are any recent program you have installed that you don't recognize or don't want.

1. Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features
2. Sort by the **Installed On** Column.
3. Try to recall the date when the problem started and see if you can find any uncommon software that you didn't install or that could of caused a problem. Remove that program.

[image]

Ok, since you have specified that none of this works, I would assume it is a virus/malware/adware on your computer that is hidden onto your computer either in temporary folders or inside ProgramData (Most probable).

I would recommend scanning your computer with [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/) and to remove all suspicious files that is finds. After that restart you computer and run the rootkit removal tool, [TDSSKiller](http://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/TDSSKiller). Restart your computer once again and re-run both of the software again to double check all of the traces have been removed. Let me know how it works out.

Let me know how it went and what you found out to be that cause or if you still need more help.

Comment: i tried it all but still same

Comment: I gave you a detailed answer on how to determine what could be the root cause. Can you please provide details on what is happening? Is there an extension you found, is there a program you had to remove? Without specific details about what you did or found, I'm just speculating.

Comment: i did delete the default user for chrome and then checked the extensions for unknown ones. checked all installed programs for something unusual then restarted the laptop. but still the same tab opening.

Comment: So you did not find either an extension or a program that could be causing this issue?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Ok, check the edit to my post and try that.